# How to Calculate Euclidean distance from sf data frame points in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gis, euclidean-distance, spatial-data

How do I calculate Euclidean distance in km from a spatial point that has been converted from a geometry column into a data frame. (The points are points which were derived from a spatial join of spatial data and polygon centroids)

I tried `data_sample <- data_sample %>% mutate(distance= distm(cbind(origin_y,origin_x), cbind(dest_y,dest_x),fun  = distHaversine)/1000)`

and the error i'm getting is
**Error in .pointsToMatrix(x) : longitude > 360**

```
Below is a sample data frame
data_sample <- data.frame(
    origin_x = c(
        623613.87,
        625678.02,
        625678.02,
        624359.91,
        628136.40,
        628136.40,
        628136.40,
        628136.40,
        632329.70
    ),
    origin_y = c(
        6438093.66,
        6455468.02,
        6455468.02,
        6449819.06,
        6462017.42,
        6462017.42,
        6462017.42,
        6462017.42,
        6446947.75
    ),
    dest_x = c(
        659627.84,
        642136.20,
        642136.20,
        630395.03,
        628422.74,
        642136.20,
        642136.20,
        659627.84,
        659627.84
    ),
    dest_y = c(
        6473200.36,
        6456562.78,
        6456562.78,
        6451979.98,
        6459817.02,
        6456562.78,
        6456562.78,
        6473200.36,
        6473200.36)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason not to use the `sf` builtin function `st_distance`??

```
library(sf)
# Using your data, but separate data.frames
origin_df <- data.frame(
    origin_x = c(623613.87,
            625678.02,
            625678.02,
            624359.91,
            628136.40,
            628136.40,
            628136.40,
            628136.40,
            632329.70
        ),         
    origin_y = c(
            6438093.66,
            6455468.02,
            6455468.02,
            6449819.06,
            6462017.42,
            6462017.42,
            6462017.42,
            6462017.42,
            6446947.75)
    )
    
dest_df <- data.frame(
    dest_x = c(
            659627.84,
            642136.20,
            642136.20,
            630395.03,
            628422.74,
            642136.20,
            642136.20,
            659627.84,
            659627.84
        ),
    dest_y = c(
            6473200.36,
            6456562.78,
            6456562.78,
            6451979.98,
            6459817.02,
            6456562.78,
            6456562.78,
            6473200.36,
            6473200.36)
    )
# Now convert to sf objects
# Just guessing at the CRS. Replace with the correct one
origin_sf = st_as_sf(origin_df, coords=c("origin_x", "origin_y"), crs="EPSG:32632")  
dest_sf <- st_as_sf(dest_df, coords=c("dest_x", "dest_y"), crs="EPSG:32632")

# Now get the distance matrix, (will be in meters, since the CRS units are meters
dist_matrix <- st_distance(origin_sf, dest_sf)
# Dispaly in kilometers
(dist_matrix)
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     [,6]     [,7]     [,8]
 [1,] 50.29400 26.15693 26.15693 15.453608 22.249261 26.15693 26.15693 50.29400
 [2,] 38.30178 16.49455 16.49455  5.866567  5.142693 16.49455 16.49455 38.30178
 [3,] 38.30178 16.49455 16.49455  5.866567  5.142693 16.49455 16.49455 38.30178
 [4,] 42.31444 19.01248 19.01248  6.410324 10.791932 19.01248 19.01248 42.31444
 [5,] 33.41809 15.02490 15.02490 10.288421  2.218953 15.02490 15.02490 33.41809
 [6,] 33.41809 15.02490 15.02490 10.288421  2.218953 15.02490 15.02490 33.41809
 [7,] 33.41809 15.02490 15.02490 10.288421  2.218953 15.02490 15.02490 33.41809
 [8,] 33.41809 15.02490 15.02490 10.288421  2.218953 15.02490 15.02490 33.41809
 [9,] 37.87331 13.73376 13.73376  5.391316 13.449255 13.73376 13.73376 37.87331
          [,9]
 [1,] 50.29400
 [2,] 38.30178
 [3,] 38.30178
 [4,] 42.31444
 [5,] 33.41809
 [6,] 33.41809
 [7,] 33.41809
 [8,] 33.41809
 [9,] 37.87331
```

And responding to the additional comment from william-g-k:

```
dist_km = dist_matrix / 1000
dist_km = as.data.frame(matrix(dist_km, nrow=1))
```

Comment: thanks works perfectly, but how do I add the distances as a column to a data frame?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure but looks like a problem with the coordinate system. I guess the `distm()`function takes values in degrees for latitude and longitude. Before converting the geometry column to data frame change the coordinate system of your data. From package 'sf' use `st_crs()` to find the current coordinate system and change to something like WGS 84 using `st_transform()`.

Comment: So it happens that st_as_sf cannot take 4 columns with longitude and latitude (origin_x, origin_y & dest_x,dest_y) at the same time so its quite difficult to convert the geographic columns to geometry.

Comment: How about breaking into two dataframe  and you can still use distm(), I guess.

Comment: @Micha method works like how I want it but I need to convert it into a single column and add to a data frame. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, but isn't that simple matrix manipulation?
see my edits to the answer...